# Displaying an array of events in full calendar

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, fullcalendar

I am trying to integrate the arshaw's jQuery fullcalendar into my rails application. When I click on the calendar tab it should display the calendar with the list of tasks in the database on the corresponding date.

In calendar controller

```
    def index

    @task=Task.find_all_by_pm_id(params[:u])
      @task.each do |t|
        @task_name=t.task_name
        @end_date=t.due_date
      end
    end

In the Calenders/index.html.erb

    <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        var date = new Date();
        var d = <%=@end_date.day%>;
        var m = <%=@end_date.month%>-1;
        var y = <%=@end_date.year%>;
        var calendar = $('#calender').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            events: [
                {
                    title: '<%=@task_name%>',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d)
                },

            ],
            editable: true

        });

    });

</script>
```

Now it is displaying only the last task name. I need to display all the task name on particular dates.  Any inputs on this will be appreciated. Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
events: [
{
title: '<%=@task_name%>',
start: new Date(y, m, d)
}
],
```

should contain an array of events, in your code you are filling it with the only one with the @task_name, try to change in something like 
    events : <%=task%> 
but check the input respects the JSON array format